# fatal error using android shared preference

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, nullpointerexception, fatal-error

I am working on my first android project and I am using android studio. The project was running fine on my test device and then I chose to clean project and now the app won't run, the exception that is thrown is:

```
Unable to instantiate activity
ComponentInfo{com.lonerganonline.league_of_ireland/com.lonerganonline.league_of_ireland.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

as i have no idea of where the error is orrignating i do not know what code to post.
[image]

Main Activity:

```
package com.lonerganonline.league_of_ireland;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private Spinner spinner;
private SharedPreferences favTeam ;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    favTeam = this.getSharedPreferences("com.lonerganonline.league_of_ireland", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    /*if (favTeam.contains("team")){
        setContentView(R.layout.my_home);
    }
    else{*/
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   // }



    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.selectTeam);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.teams_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
      adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public String getTeam(){
        String team ="";
        favTeam.getString("team","Not Defined");
        return team;
    }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    public void submitMyTeam(View v){

        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        String selectedTeam = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        txt.setText(selectedTeam);
        editor  = favTeam.edit();
        editor.putString("team", selectedTeam);
        editor.apply();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyTeamActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/selectTeam"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="163dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/submit"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="submitMyTeam"
    android:layout_below="@+id/selectTeam"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_above="@+id/selectTeam"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.lonerganonline.league_of_ireland/com.lonerganonline.league_of_ireland.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5137)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:718)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.lonerganonline.league_of_ireland.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:19)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
        at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2154)
```

Comment: Please add your code for MainActivity

Comment: Is that the full stack trace?

Comment: Post MainActivity please

Comment: Check the logcat output for the full stack trace, it will line up with your `MainActivity` code and point to the problem.  If you post both the full logcat output and your `MainActivity` code the folks here will likely be able to assist quickly.

Comment: `favTeam` is most likely null

Comment: init `editor` after init `favTeam`

Comment: Good spot but now i am getting a different error. will edit above

Comment: the app now runs but has that error

Comment: you have changed stack trace?

Comment: yes as when I init my variables in the right order the error changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

private SharedPreferences.Editor editor  = favTeam.edit();

Change `private SharedPreferences.Editor editor  = favTeam.edit();` 
to `private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;` 
It leads to NullPointerException becauce it tries to init editor while construction of Activity object but before executing of `onCreate()` where you do initialization of `favTeam` class member.

Then in method `onCreate()` add next line 
`editor  = favTeam.edit();`
after your 
`favTeam = this.getSharedPreferences("com.lonerganonline.league_of_ireland", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Comment: Also, there's no reason keeping these as class members in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Such an approximation error i've seen only when the null pointer exception occurs at layout inflation time. The simplest form of such an error is trying to set anything like listeners or menus in onCreate. This happens because when you say something like "set fragment", you don't really load the fragment. You add a job for the inflater somewhere on a queue. You have no guarantee that all layout is set by the end of onCreate.

My bet is to move this later in the application startup flow (try onStart() )

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.teams_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);move this
```